# How to update only specific page's Likes count using SignalR in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a problem in implementing SignalR in my MVC application. I am updating my posts like count every time a person clicks on like button of a specific album post page. But I am facing a problem here that when I click on Like button of a specific page, the likes count of the other pages is also incremented.

so here is my NotificationHub code:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{

    public void Like(Guid albumId, Guid managerId)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        var LikeCounter = SaveLike(albumId, managerId);
        Clients.All.updateLikeCount(LikeCounter);
    }

    public int? SaveLike(Guid albumId, Guid managerId)
    {
        // my implementation code
    }


    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }

}
```

This is my jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
        var albumClient = $.connection.notificationHub;
        albumClient.client.updateLikeCount = function (likes) {
            var counter = $(".like-count");
            $(counter).fadeOut(function () {
                $(this).text(likes);
                $(this).fadeIn();
            });
        };
        $(".like-button").on("click", function () {
            var albumId = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var managerId = $(this).attr("id");
            albumClient.server.like(albumId, managerId);
        });

        $.connection.hub.start();

    });
```

So kindly help me what I am doing wrong or what modifications are needed in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me point out few mistakes in the code.

```
$(function () {
    var albumClient = $.connection.notificationHub;
    albumClient.client.updateLikeCount = function (likes) {
        var counter = $(".like-count"); //selects all like button. Thats why every page buttons are updated.
        $(counter).fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).text(likes);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    };
    $(".like-button").on("click", function () {
        var albumId = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var managerId = $(this).attr("id");
        albumClient.server.like(albumId, managerId); // you are calling the server method and the server has no clue of which button to update.
    });

    $.connection.hub.start();

});
```

So as pointed out in the comments. Firstly you are calling the server by passing some data which is fine. But the server has to later send ping to the client and update what?? which button?? it has no clue. And you are using a class selector for the buttons `$(".like-count")` which will select all the buttons with that class name, And later you update all the buttons because of this.

So the solution is **each of your button must have a unique id** like to which page it belongs or any other data which makes it unique. You can still have the same class and same event binded to on click. Only change would be like below.

```
$(".like-button").on("click", function () {
   var albumId = $(this).attr("data-id");
   var managerId = $(this).attr("id");
   albumClient.server.like(albumId, managerId, $(this).attr('id')); //pass the id of the like button as well to your signalR code
});
```

Modify your SignalR code to below.

```
public void Like(Guid albumId, Guid managerId,string buttonID) //include parameter to accept button Id
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
    var LikeCounter = SaveLike(albumId, managerId);
    Clients.All.updateLikeCount(LikeCounter,buttonID); //pass back the button id as well.
}
```

Now to the last change.

```
albumClient.client.updateLikeCount = function (likes,btnId) { // input parameter
        //directly change the button likes.
        $('#'+btnId).fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).text(likes);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    };
```

let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Users to a Groups on page load:

> `this.Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, postName)`

then:

> `Clients.Group(postName).updateLikeCount(LikeCounter);`

Comment: He wants to update it to all active users.. Not to any specific group

Comment: It updates for all users, because all users connecting to the [postName] group on page load, and when someone clicks like button, it will increment like counter only on that post (or page etc)